# Login con laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, login

Hola tengo el siguiente problema, tengo 3 tablas , tabla login, tabla laboratorio y tabla empleado, cada laboratorio tendrá un usuario y contraseña para acceder a su vista correspondiente e igualmente cada empleado sera igual, no se como implementar el login en ese caso, soy nuevo manejando laravel. Pensaba meter todo en una sola tabla usuario pero creo que me complico algo así

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('usu_labCeco');
        $table->string('usu_labDireccion');
        $table->string('usu_labLider');
        $table->string('usu_empNom');
        $table->string('usu_empCampo'),
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

No se si me explique muy bien pero tal vez me puedan ayudar gracias.

Comment: Debes mostrar lo que has intentado, además de la estructura de las tablas (las migraciones), todo como texto y no como imagen.

Comment: Dentro de tu proyecto en consolsa ejecuta `php artisan key:generate --ansi` y luego `php artisan make:auth`, con eso haces tu sistema de login

Comment: ¿Qué tiene de distinto acceder como laboratorio y como empleado?

Comment: Muestra diferentes interfaces

Answer (score 1):

Laravel por defecto utiliza la tabla users y el modelo User para manejar el login. Yo lo que te recomendaría es utilizar una relación polimórfica [(ver documentación)](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships), quedando algo así:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->morphs('user');
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

donde `$table->morphs('user')` creará 2 atributos adicionales en tu tabla , llamados **user_id** (integer) y **user_type** (string) ([ver documentación)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations). El propósito de user_id es guardar la id de la tabla laboratorio o empleado. A su vez, user_type guarda el modelo de laboratorio o empleado. De esta forma podrías guardar en la tabla users un laboratorio o un empleado y laravel sabrá identificar cuando es uno o cuando es otro...

La gracia de hacerlo de esta forma, es que Eloquent te permite navegar (teniendo tu instancia User) a Laboratorio o a Empleado, dependiendo a quién pertenezca ese registro. Para ello, debes crear un nuevo método en tu modelo User, quedando asi:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Obtener Laboratorio o Empleado
     */
    public function padre() //Puede ser cualquier otro nombre
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

De la misma forma el modelo Laboratorio y Empleado quedarían así:

```
class Laboratorio extends Model
{
    /**
     * Obtener Usuario del Laboratorio.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        //El segundo parametro corresponde a este nombre: $table->morphs('user');
        return $this->morphOne('App\User', 'user'); 

    }
}

class Empleado extends Model
{
    /**
     * Obtener Usuario del Empleado.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\User', 'user');
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANTE**

Cuando crees un nuevo User, el atributo **user_type** debe ser 'App\Empleado' o 'App\Laboratorio' (Correspondiente a la ruta del modelo Empleado o Laboratorio), dependiendo de que si ese usuario corresponde a un Empleado o Laboratorio.
(`$user->user_type = 'App\Empleado' || 'App\Laboratorio';`)

**EJEMPLOS**

Si tienes una instancia de User, puedes obtener al Empleado o al Laboratorio de la siguiente forma

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
$padre = $user->padre;

if($user->user_type == 'App\Empleado') {
   //$padre es una instancia de Empleado
   ....
} else if($user->user_type == 'App\Laboratorio'') {
   //$padre es una instancia de Laboratorio
   ....
}
```

Para ver la instancia $padre puedes hacerle un `dd($padre);`

---

Eso haría yo amigo... La otra alternativa es crear session por separado para la tabla Empleado y la tabla Laboratorio. Te dejaré un tutorial de eso igual por si te interesa esa alternativa [AQUÍ](https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel)

Nos cuentas como te va, Éxito!